# Issues with connecting to Accumulo from Spark Shell

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zookeeper, accumulo

I'm having trouble with a Scala application running in spark-shell where I'm trying to connect to an Accumulo data store.

```
   "accumulo.instance.name" -> "accumulo",
   "accumulo.zookeepers" -> "zookeeper",
   "accumulo.user" -> "user",
   "accumulo.password" -> "password",
   "accumulo.catalog" -> "catalog"
)
val dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params)
```

After attempting to make the connection, the spark-shell hangs for a long period without returning. I'm also seeing some warning messages, specifically

```
ThriftTransportPool: Server localhost:9997 (120000) had 20 failures in a short time period, will not complain anymore
SingletonReservation: An Accumulo Client was garbage collected without being closed.
```

I have checked and my Accumulo server is running correctly. I've also ensured that the user credentials are correct and the user has appropriate permissions to access the Accumulo table. I have tried confirming Spark and Accumulo are compatible, examining the configuration and checking resource allocation but none of these steps have resolved the issue.

I'm wondering if anyone might have suggestions as to what could be causing this issue and how I might go about resolving it. Any insights would be greatly appreciated!